# match names of a geographic dictionary from text in python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, text

I have a list of GeoNames city names I use to export place names from a table of text. How can I match a multi-segment name (e.g. "Santa Barbara", "Los Angeles", etc.) from the list of city names with the text? Cities names that have more than one word are not recognized.

The code which I have tried is:

```
import csv
import time

#import tab-delimited keywords file
f = open('cities_key.txt','r')
allKeywords = f.read().lower().split(\n)
f.close()
#print(len(allKeywords))

allTexts = []
fullRow = []
with open('adrl_title_desc.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        #the full row for each entry, which will be used to recreate the improved CSV file in a moment
        fullRow.append((row['title'], row['description']))

        #the column we want to parse for our keywords
        row = row['description'].lower()
        allTexts.append(row)
        #print(len(row))

#a flag used to keep track of which row is being printed to the CSV file
counter = 0

#use the current date and time to create a unique output filename
timestr = time.strftime(%Y-%m-%d-(%H-%M-%S))
filename = 'output-' + str(timestr) + '.csv'

#Open the new output CSV file to append ('a') rows one at a time.
with open(filename, 'a') as csvfile:

    #define the column headers and write them to the new file
    fieldnames = ['title', 'description', 'place']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    #define the output for each row and then print to the output csv file
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

    #this is the same as before, for currentRow in fullRow:
    for entry in allTexts:

        matches = 0
        storedMatches = []

        #for each entry:
        #HOW TO RESOLVE MULTI-PART NAMES? e.g. Santa Barbara
        allWords = entry.split(' ')
        for words in allWords:

            #remove punctuation that will interfere with matching
            words = words.replace(',', '')
            words = words.replace('.', '')
            words = words.replace(';', '')

            #if a keyword match is found, store the result.
            if words in allKeywords:
                if words in storedMatches:
                    continue
                else:
                    storedMatches.append(words)
                matches += 1

        #send any matches to a new row of the csv file.
        if matches == 0:
            newRow = fullRow[counter]
        else:
            matchTuple = tuple(storedMatches)
            newRow = fullRow[counter] + matchTuple

        #write the result of each row to the csv file
        writer.writerows([newRow])
        counter += 1
```

**City names:**

[image]

**Description:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good work putting the effort before asking for help. Here are my changes to your code. I retained your code and commented it out so that you know what I was doing. Using regular expressions is the best bet for you in this situation. I am using the same loops as you used. I did not split the description. Instead, I ran through the entire description looking for the city names using the regular expression module. I also did not use list for storedMatches. Using a set will make sure you are not adding duplicates. Checking if the city was already added is one more check you don't need. I used Python 3.7.

I used `import re` to import the regular expression module.

```
import csv
import time
#Raj006 import regular expression module
import re

#import tab-delimited keywords file
f = open('cities_key.txt','r')
#Raj006 Not making the keywords lower. Will match with lower using regex
#allKeywords = f.read().lower().split('\n')
allKeywords = f.read().split('\n')
f.close()
#print(len(allKeywords))

allTexts = []
fullRow = []
with open('adrl_title_desc.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        #the full row for each entry, which will be used to recreate the improved CSV file in a moment
        fullRow.append((row['title'], row['description']))

        #the column we want to parse for our keywords
        #row = row['description'].lower()
        #Raj006 not making description lower as regular expression takes care of case-insensitive search.
        row = row['description']
        allTexts.append(row)
        #print(len(row))

#a flag used to keep track of which row is being printed to the CSV file
counter = 0

#use the current date and time to create a unique output filename
timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-(%H-%M-%S)")
filename = 'output-' + str(timestr) + '.csv'

#Open the new output CSV file to append ('a') rows one at a time.
with open(filename, 'a') as csvfile:

    #define the column headers and write them to the new file
    fieldnames = ['title', 'description', 'place']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    #define the output for each row and then print to the output csv file
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

    #this is the same as before, for currentRow in fullRow:
    for entry in allTexts:

        #matches = 0
        #Raj006 Changed this to set to make sure the list is unique (which is basically the definiton of the set)
        storedMatches = set()
        #Raj006 looping through all cities and checking if the city name exists in the description.
        #Raj006 re.search looks for the lookup word in the entire string (re.search(lookupword,string)).
        for eachcity in allKewords:
            if re.search('\\b'+eachcity+'\\b',entry,re.IGNORECASE):
                #Adding the matched city to the set
                storedMatches.add(eachcity)
        #for each entry:
        #HOW TO RESOLVE MULTI-PART NAMES? e.g. Santa Barbara
        #allWords = entry.split(' ')
        #for words in allWords:

            #remove punctuation that will interfere with matching
            #words = words.replace(',', '')
            #words = words.replace('.', '')
            #words = words.replace(';', '')

            #if a keyword match is found, store the result.
            #if words in allKeywords:
                #if words in storedMatches:
                    #continue
                #else:
                    #storedMatches.append(words)
                #matches += 1

        #send any matches to a new row of the csv file.
        #if matches == 0:
        #Raj006 Just using the length of the set to determine if any matches found. Reducing one more unnecessary check.
        if len(storedMatches)==0:
            newRow = fullRow[counter]
        else:
            matchTuple = tuple(storedMatches)
            newRow = fullRow[counter] + matchTuple

        #write the result of each row to the csv file
        writer.writerows([newRow])
        counter += 1
```

Update: Added ignore case to re.search.

I improved the code above to remove unnecessary loops and confusion in variable names. I don't have the source file, so couldn't test it. If I find any issues, I will update it later.

```
import csv
import time
import re
allCities = open('cities_key.txt','r').readlines()
timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-(%H-%M-%S)")
with open('adrl_title_desc.csv') as descriptions,open('output-' + str(timestr) + '.csv', 'w', newline='') as output:
    descriptions_reader = csv.DictReader(descriptions)
    fieldnames = ['title', 'description', 'cities']
    output_writer = csv.DictWriter(output, delimiter='|', fieldnames=fieldnames)
    output_writer.writeheader()
    for eachRow in descriptions_reader:
        title = eachRow['title']
        description = eachRow['description']
        citiesFound = set()
        for eachcity in allCities:
            eachcity=eachcity.strip()
            if re.search('\\b'+eachcity+'\\b',description,re.IGNORECASE):
                citiesFound.add(eachcity)
        if len(citiesFound)>0:
            output_writer.writerow({'title': title, 'description': description, 'cities': ", ".join(citiesFound)})
```

This code has the csv delimiter set to `|` instead of a `,`, as I was using it for cities.

Test files.
cities_key.txt

```
San Francisco
San Gabriel
San Jacinto
San Jose
San Juan Capistrano
Haiti
San Mateo
```

adrl_title_desc.csv

```
key,title,description
1,title1,"some description here with San Francisco"
2,title2,"some, more description here with Haitian info"
3,title3,"some city not a wordSan Mateo"
4,title4,"some city San Juan Capistrano just normal"
5,title5,"multiple cities in one San Jacinto,San Jose and San Gabriel end"
```

Code output

```
title|description|cities
title1|some description here with San Francisco|San Francisco
title4|some city San Juan Capistrano just normal|San Juan Capistrano
title5|multiple cities in one San Jacinto,San Jose and San Gabriel end|San Jacinto, San Jose, San Gabriel
```

@itsme, now, this should not go wrong with Python 3.x. I fixed the error with `'\\b'+eachcity+'\\b'` (missed + sign). You were not able to find any matches because when you use `readlines()` for some reason it retains line endings. I used `strip()` to remove them. I had to use `newline=''` in open file dialogue as the csv writer was creating a new line after each row. You can see that in my sample, you can't find a city for key 2 and key 3 as the cities were not separated as words from the rest of the text.

Comment: I updated my code for re.search to just look for words instead of a substring. Check the documentation on Python site https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search.

Comment: Updated code gives an error `'\\b'+eachcity'\\b'` of  `'`

Comment: It is running fine on my machine with two backslashes. What is the actual error message?

Comment: ok I have run this code 
and in a output file 
just this is show in Ist cell " title|description|cities "

Comment: Updated code, and tested. Provided the test files and output.

Comment: @itsme, please, mark as the answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: Ist of all Extreamly sorry for kate reply ,i was too buzy , yes thankyou so much your code is work acccording to my need thankyou so much ,

Comment: Improved code by removing one more check to see `if len(citiesFound)==0`.